# How to send large Base64 data to NavController in Ionic 2/3?

Tags: ionic-framework, base64, ionic3

I am trying to send `Base64` data as string to another page using `NavController` using below code:

```
  ConvertHTMLToPDF = () => {
    let htmlGrid = document.getElementById('customContent');
    const options = {background: "white", height: htmlGrid.clientHeight, width: htmlGrid.clientWidth};
    html2canvas(htmlGrid, options).then((canvas) => {
      let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
      let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG");
      //Add image Canvas to PDF
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 20, 20);

      let pdfData = doc.output('datauri');
      let obj = {PDFSrc: pdfData};
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('SaveConsentLetterPage', obj);
    });
  };
```

This is perfectly working when the Base64 data is small in size like **3Kb** or **4Kb**. But, when the data is like **1.2Mb**, the NavController can redirect to SaveConsentLetterPage. It crashes the application.

Why is that? Is there any limit to send data with `setRoot` to another page in `Ionic 2/3`?

Comment: Save it to temp directory, send its patch as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with below line:

```
let pdfData = doc.output('datauri');
```

This opens the data uri/pdfData in **current window** and as a result, preventing to go the next page.

But, below line returns only the data uri string and as a result, can easily pass the data to next page.

```
doc.output('datauristring');
```